# How to use punctuation marks in LuaLaTeX with unicode-math?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, luatex, unicode-math

I also posts this here: http://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/3000/interpunktion-in-lualatex-mit-unicode-math-von-hauptschriftart.
The problem is that I want to have the `\period` symbol (also `range="002E` does not work) from the mainfont, but when I run this:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}
%
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
%
\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular}
%
\setmathfont{LatinModernMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[range=\period]{MinionPro-Regular}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Regular}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}

\begin{document}
    $\bigl(x^2+5\bigr).$
\end{document}
```

I get the following result:

[image]

Are there any ideas to solve this problem? Thanks for help.

I may think the problem lies in the `\right.`- and `\left.`-delimiters, because you won't get the incorrect result if you use `\left` and `\right` instead of `\bigl(` and `\bigr)`. It seems as if `range=\period` makes them visible.

Is there a possibility to fix this?

Comment: Indeed, when `range=\period` is issued, when I trace the list built by `$\left(x\right.)$` I get `\right"42E000` instead of the expected `\right"0` that would denote an empty delimiter. This happens also with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @egreg Anything new on this subject? Should I report this to the unicode-math maintainers, as it still happens with an up-to-date miktex?

Comment: I forgot this question; on my TeX Live 2014 the problem seems solved. Using `unicode-math` 2014/06/30 v0.7f.

Answer (score 8):

The problem has not yet been solved with version 0.7f of `unicode-math`, so this answer is just an attempt to see what's happening; an ugly workaround is proposed.

This is what I get when adding `\showlists` to the definition of `\big` with

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\big}{\n@space}{\n@space\showlists}{}{}
\makeatother
```

from `$\big($`.

### `unicode-math` version 0.7e

```
\mathinner
.\left"28000
.\mathord
..\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0
.\right"42E000
### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 20
spacefactor 1000
### math mode entered at line 20
### math mode entered at line 20
\mathord
### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 18
spacefactor 1000
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\write-{}
```

### `unicode-math` version 0.7f

```
### math mode entered at line 20
\mathinner
.\left"28000
.\mathord
..\vbox(8.5+0.0)x0.0
.\right"0
### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 20
spacefactor 1000
### math mode entered at line 20
### math mode entered at line 20
\mathord
### restricted horizontal mode entered at line 18
spacefactor 1000
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\write-{}
```

The output is obtained with XeLaTeX, but with LuaLaTeX it's similar. We can clearly see

```
.\right"42E000
```

with the 0.7e version, that shows exactly a centered dot after `\right`. With the 0.7f version we get

```
.\right"0
```

that is, the expected null delimiter.

Here's the PDF output from the OP's example.

### Output with `unicode-math` version 0.7e (and TeX Live 2013)

[image]

### Output with `unicode-math` version 0.7f (and TeX Live 2014)

[image]

### Where's the magic?

In passing from 0.7e to 0.7f the entry for `\period` has been removed from `unicode-math-table.tex`, so `range=\period` does nothing. If we change `range=\period` to `range=\mathperiod` (the new name), the centered dot reappears.

### Workaround

```
\documentclass{standalone}
%
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
%
\setmainfont{MinionPro-Regular}
%
\setmathfont{LatinModernMath-Regular}
\setmathfont[range=\mathperiod]{MinionPro-Regular}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Regular}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-Bold}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-It}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfit/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{MinionPro-BoldIt}

\Udelcodenum`.=1073741824 % reset the right delcode

\begin{document}
$\bigl(x^2+5\bigr).$
\end{document}
```

[image]

According to my PDF previewer, the final period is in Minion Pro.

Comment: I think the point behind the closing bracket is still set in Latin Modern (Compare to a dot directly after the `$` and use Cambria Math for clearer visibility - the point in the math environment is still set in Cambria Math and thus a small square). It can be avoided if range=\mathperiod is issued, but this leads to exactly the behaviour observed for version 0.7e and `range=\period`.

Comment: @John I don't think it's a font problem: since there's `\right"0` no character is typeset, it's just a signal for inserting `\nulldelimiterspace` (that's later removed by `\n@space` in the definition of `\big`).

Comment: It depends on which period we mean. If I only change Latin Modern to Cambria Math in your working example above, I don't get the centered dot after the bracket, _but_ the final dot right before the dollar sign is still typeset in Cambria Math (a square, not a circle like it should be in MinionPro). I'm pretty sure in your working example the final dot is typeset in Latin Modern, but as the period is very similar to the one of Minion Pro this is not really visible. You get the correct final period if `\mathperiod` is used as range, but then the centered dots appear again.

Comment: @John You're right, the bug is still there. The entry for `\period` has been removed from `unicode-math-table.tex` and that somewhat explains what happens.

Comment: @John I added a workaround

Comment: Thanks a lot! This works fine with XeLaTeX, LuaLatex however issues an error `! Invalid delimiter code.` The pdf output is correct nonetheless, as far as I can see.

Comment: @John, egreg getting the same error as John I set `\Udelcodenum`.=0` and it works!

Answer (score 3):

The question is somewhat general, but refers to the specific problem of periods, which have a special meaning for TeX delimiters. (Choosing other punctuation from other fonts works fine, right?) My understanding is that they should always have delcode of zero; unicode-math has a line of code to ensure this, and due to a broader bug in how `range` is interpreted it's not being run.

The next version of unicode-math will fix this. (You can check out the development version on Github but I can't guarantee it will work from night-to-night.) Sorry for the slow reply.