# Full stop missing in MnSymbol - replacement renders brackets with cdots - Why?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, unicode-math, mnsymbol

I'm close to give up [**my fight**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238209/general-guide-on-how-to-set-up-minion-pro-for-math-in-lualatex/238210) for **MnSymbol** in **unicode-math**. I realized I already replaced so many missing and faulty characters, that there is barely something left of MnSymol. So probably I will just go the other way around in the future, use a different math font and replace the symbols I don't like with MnSymbol.

---

However, please allow one last question before I carry MnSymbol to his grave:

Obviously the full stop is missing in MnSymbol:

```
$\Bigg[\bigg(\big[ 42 \big]\bigg)\Bigg].$
```

[image]

When I replace the full stop with a different font, all brackets get followed by a `\cdot`:

```
\setmathfont[range={"002E} ]{XITS Math}
```

[image]

which won't happen if I replace the whole math font:

```
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
```

[image]

---

Besides looking for a solution, I actually would like to know

## Why?

I'm replacing a certain unicode character and others are affected as well, **that does not make any sense**?

---

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Minion Pro}
\setmathfont[range={"005B,"005D,"0028,"0029,"007B,"007D} ]{XITS Math} % brackets

\begin{document}

$\Bigg[\bigg(\big[ 42 \big]\bigg)\Bigg].$
\setmathfont[range={"002E} ]{XITS Math}
$\Bigg[\bigg(\big[ 42 \big]\bigg)\Bigg].$
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
$\Bigg[\bigg(\big[ 42 \big]\bigg)\Bigg].$

\end{document}
```

---

### For future reference:

A full solution can be found [**here**](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207554/36835), but

```
\Udelcodenum`.=1073741824
```

needs to be changed to

```
\Udelcodenum`.=0
```

Comment: `Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 16--17` :(

Comment: @DavidCarlisle no line breaks and the warning is gone but the problem persists.

Comment: yes the problem is unrelated, but it's demoralising fixing a document that's infinitely bad:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see your point ;) I changed the MWE :)

Comment: Isn't this the same as http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154001/how-to-use-punctuation-marks-in-lualatex-with-unicode-math ?

Comment: @egreg yes it seems, couldn't find it. I will see how this helps and this question can be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I tried the proposed workaround and it seems to work, provided you remove the `\setmathfont[range={"002E} ]{XITS Math}` instruction.

Comment: @egreg, yes the workaround, but with `\Udelcodenum`.=0` works for me too! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the font, but the problem's not font  specific.

The `\showlists` output shows that in the first case `.` is set to pull the `.` from `\fam0` In a classic TeX set up `\fam0` is used for the text Roman font as used for `\log` and friends, but with `unicode-math` the Roman characters come from the Roman alphabet in the upper plane of the Unicode font in `\fam1` and in fact `\texfont0` is shown as being `\nullfont` which has no characters.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{MnSymbol}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{num,latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{Arial}
\setmathfont[range={"005B,"005D,"0028,"0029,"007B,"007D} ]{XITS Math} % brackets

\begin{document}
\showoutput
\showthe\textfont0
$\Bigg[\bigg(\big[ 42 \big]\bigg)\Bigg].\showlists$

\setmathfont[range={"002E} ]{XITS Math} 

$\Bigg[\bigg(\big[ 42 \big]\bigg)\Bigg].\showlists$

\setmathfont{XITS Math}

$\Bigg[\bigg(\big[ 42 \big]\bigg)\Bigg].$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Like yesterday I can't compile code containing the commands `\showoutput` and `\showlists` (it takes forever) - I use `lualatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` to compile

Comment: @thewaywewalk `\showxxx` makes it pause to show the result  `\showoutput` sets the interaction mode back, change it to `\showoutput\nonstopmode` then it won't stop and you need to look in the log