# XeLaTeX: How to prevent the use of subscripted and superscripted versions of Arabic numerals in the math mode?

Tags: xetex

I use the [Libertinus](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertinus?lang=en) font family in my documents. Libertinus Serif contains [superscripted and subscripted versions of Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superscripts_and_Subscripts), whereas Libertinus Math don't.

In the math mode, for some reason those glyphs are used (leading to unpleasant kerning etc etc) with anything less than `\normalsize`, explicitly (that is, through `\small`, `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize`, and `\tiny)` or implicitly (for example, through `^` and `_`). Wrapping the superscripted/subscripted numerals in `\mathrm` helps as a workaround. But surely there must be a better way?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}

\begin{document}

$1234567890^{1234567890}$

$1234567890^\mathrm{1234567890}$

\end{document}
```

[image: 1234567890^1234567890]

Comment: No “superscript digits” are used. If you compare `{\footnotesize $1234567890$}` and `{\footnotesize 1234567890}` you can see the same effect.

Comment: @egreg Weird... It seems anothing smaller than `\normalsize` uses those glyphs... Let me rephrase the question to reflect this.

Comment: As soon as you use a font size less than 10pt, the shape of the digits in Libertinus Math changes.

Comment: @egreg Not entirely accurate. With the default font size set to 12pt, `\small` digits, which are larger than 10pt, still use the alternative glyphs.

Comment: `\setmathfont[SizeFeatures={Size={-}}]{Libertinus Math}` alone seems to work perfectly.

Comment: I wouldn't disable `ssty` for everything: also letters are affected.

Comment: @egreg After some more experimentation it seems I would want to disable `ssty` for everything: https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/15276544/16033841/4c2883ce-3206-11e6-9aa3-4e367394e662.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Section 4.2 in the manual of `unicode-math` specifies that the `Style=MathScript` and `Style=MathScriptScript` are automatically applied for sizes less than the font's base size.

The Libertinus Math font happens to support these features by defining specific shapes for the digits.

You can disable this by setting a different font for the digits only by specifying a range:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ifxetex} % for the ugly workaround

\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[
]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[
  range=`0-`9,
  script-features={},
  sscript-features={},
]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}[range=\int] % just for safety

% using range has unexpected consequences on \left and \right
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/207554/4427
\ifxetex
  \Udelcodenum`.=1073741824 % reset the right delcode
fi    
\begin{document}

$1234567890^{1234567890}$

$1234567890^\mathrm{1234567890}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly, but it seems to clash with the package `mathtools` in handling `\left.` and `\right.` in, for example, `$\left[ \frac{1}{2} \right.$`.

Comment: @Taiki That, unfortunately, is a bug of `unicode-math`, see https://github.com/wspr/unicode-math/issues/351 `:(` You can temporarily disable the script features globally, without using a range.

Comment: Oh no. :'( Thank you very much for the link, which lets me know that `\setmathfont[range={\dummysymbol}]{<some suitable font>}` helps.

Comment: I added a workaround; though ugly, it works.